# MySQL Query Ocurrences within a field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field called invoice_notes in a table called b_orders. In this field the words "Credit Card Declined" will show up several times depending on how many times the card has been declined. I am trying to write a query to select only the records where the phrase "Credit Card Declined" appears less than 4 times?

Something like this:
SELECT * FROM b_orders where invoice_notes has "Credit Card Declined" < 4 "

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the answer: http://pisceansheart.wordpress.com/2008/04/15/count-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string-using-mysql/
Quote:

```
1. Counting the number of characters in the original string
2. Temporarily ‘deleting’ the character you want to count and count the string again
3. Subtract the first count from the second to get the number of occurrences

    SELECT LENGTH('foobarfoobarfoobar') - LENGTH(REPLACE('foobarfoobarfoobar', 'b', '')) AS occurrences
```

For your specific example:

```
SELECT * FROM b_orders where (length(invoice_notes) - length(replace(invoice_notes, 'Credit Card Declined'))) < (length('Credit Card Declined') * 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
SELECT * FROM b_orders 
WHERE invoice_notes LIKE "%Credit Card Declined%" 
   AND invoice_notes NOT LIKE "%Credit Card Declined%Credit Card Declined%Credit Card Declined%Credit Card Declined%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM b_orders WHERE invoice_notes LIKE '%Credit Card Declined%' 
AND invoice_notes NOT LIKE REPEAT('%Credit Card Declined%',4);
```